# A shorter alternative to nested for loops

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, lapply

I'm performing a little calculation to compute `pij` (see below) using 2 nested `for` loops. I was wondering however if instead of 2 nested `for` loops, I could use a **shorter** R code?

```
X <- data.frame(A = 1:6, B = c(1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5))

X2 <- X * (X - 1)
  sumcol <- colSums(X)
  sumrow <- rowSums(X)

  pij <- matrix(, nrow = nrow(X), ncol = ncol(X))   ## pij HERE

  for (i in 1:length(sumrow)) {                     ## Nested for loops
    for (j in 1:length(sumcol)) {
      pij[i, j] <- X2[i, j]/(sumrow[i] * (sumrow[i] - 1))
    }
  }
```

Comment: `X2/(sumrow * (sumrow - 1))` OR `(X^2 - X)/(rowSums(X)^2 - rowSums(X))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can directly get the required `pij` matrix from `X` by performing the following calculation.

```
(X * (X - 1))/(rowSums(X) * (rowSums(X) - 1))

#          A         B
#1 0.0000000 0.0000000
#2 0.1666667 0.1666667
#3 0.1428571 0.2857143
#4 0.2142857 0.2142857
#5 0.2222222 0.2222222
#6 0.2727273 0.1818182
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, is [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454100/repeat-a-subsetting-function-by-adding-a-new-subsetting-variable-at-each-round-i) difficult to answer?